# Javascript not firing on laravel homestead app

Tags: javascript, laravel

Javascript code not firing - event listener

I have added some custom javascript to my laravel app and the code appears in my app.js file.

I have an event listener on a text field and on blur I want to insert the text inputted into another div

```
export default {
init() {
    // JavaScript to be fired on all pages

    // vanilla JS
    document.getElementById('purchasePriceId').addEventListener('blur', 
    function() {

        alert('hi');
    });


},
finalize() {
    // JavaScript to be fired on all pages, after page specific JS is fired
    },
};
```

For the time being, I have an alert which is not even firing

Comment: you should put more information like the full html and what app.js are you using

Comment: Solved the problem. There were two things I had to do add to the webpack.max.js file the resource that I am using `code`.js('resources/js/profit-loss-calc.js', 'public/js') `code` and in the custom code add the require statement `code` require ('./profit-loss-calc'); `code`